# Break line for value in power within a gather

Tags: equations

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\left\{
  \begin{aligned}\label{5}
  A&=\omega(4-i)[\lambda(2^{\omega(1.2-\textup{r})})\vee\\
  &\qquad{}\lambda(2^{\omega({\lvert 1-\textup{p} \rvert} \vee {\lvert 3-\textup{p} \rvert} \vee {\lvert 4-\textup{p} \rvert} )})]\\
  \end{aligned}
  \right.\raisetag{8\baselineskip}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

I am having trouble with a long equation, both in variables and in the power. As this is shown, for variables I can make a new line but when I apply the same thing to break the long power into another line, I face an error. Is there a specific method to do such thing? (Consider I am using a double-column template.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \left\{\!\!
  \begin{aligned}\label{5}
  A &=\omega(4-i)[\lambda(2^{\omega(\alpha)})\\
    &\qquad{}\vee\lambda(2^{\omega(\beta)})]\\
  \end{aligned}\right.\raisetag{8\baselineskip}
\end{gather}      
where $\alpha=1.2-\textup{r}$ and $\beta={\lvert 1-\textup{p}\rvert}\vee {\lvert 3-\textup{p}\rvert}\vee{\lvert 4-\textup{p}\rvert}$.

\end{document}
```

We don't normally see a power broken over two lines, but we can define `\alpha` and `\beta` or any other two unused symbols to shorten the powers and insert in text their definition.

Comment: `We` refers to?

Comment: People in the area of physical sciences and mathematics, I'm one of them!

Comment: Cool. But I am a computer geek :)